# How do i prevent a folder from deletion in windows 7 from other user in linux partition in dual booted system?

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, password-protection, user-folders

My dual booted pc is designed in a way that ,the linux partition can access the contents in windows partition while windows partition can't access contents in linux partition.So i want to create a folder in windows which does not have the visibility permission as well as modification permission in linux partition.In short i want to create a folder in windows which is prevented from modification from all users , ie without a password it can't be modified from any OS.How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest individual folder encrytion:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/encrypt-decrypt-folder-file#1TC=windows-7

Or use Bitlocker for full drive encryption:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/bitlocker-drive-encryption-overview

I'm sure there is third-party software that can accomplish this also,  but these tools should do the job. Cheers!